# Why am I never attacked? Why is the AI so peaceful?

Tags: civilization-5

I usually play prince and I usually win the games. What I hardly get ever attacked. Sometimes not even until the modern era. Is there a tweak or a mod to change this?

Or should I declare a war in the beginning of the game so that the game gets more interesting? Usually, I don't see a reason for doing this.

Comment: you try random personalities? some civs are just naturally peacefull. also if you are stronger or equals with your AI they won't attack you unless you piss enough of them off, and they gang up on you.

Comment: Generally speaking (and ignoring personalities), the AI attacks based on relative power levels.  In the early game, they will attack you if you are weak. In the late game, they will attack you if you are strong and winning. However, If you want to fight, there is a Declare War button on the diplomacy screen...

Comment: You should play against ghandi :p

Answer (score 3):

AI gets more bonuses as you increase the difficulty, prince level is the "normal balanced" difficulty. I suggest you try harder levels for more aggression.

Since after prince, at king AI gets tech, unit cost, unit amount, growth rate etc bonuses, they are more likely to grow a military faster than you and attack early.

In prince mode, since everything is equal, the human player usually has at least equal power with the AI nations. This discourages them from attacking, AI doesn't like to enter a war they cannot win.

Here check the differences:

http://www.civfanatics.com/civ5/difficulties

Comment: Good answer, but could you copy at least the basic information from the link you've provided? Stackexchange tries to stay independent and even though it encourages sources, if this site would go offline for some reason, this information would be missing.

Comment: That site has been up for 14 years, I doubt it will go offline. I see your point but  there seems to be too much data, even if I take a screen shot and post it, it may mess up the order here with such long images.

Comment: Yeah, you're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

Check your demographics screen - If your military is higher than anyone around you, they're highly unlikely to attack you. You can still piss them off enough to make them try.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to up the difficulty level.  I have the same problem while playing on Prince.  I will settle cities right next to other civilizations and buy all the land around them.  They will tell me to stop but they remain friendly.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you try a game with the following opponents and see what happens.

- Augustus (Romans)
- Attila (The Huns)
- Shaka (The Zulu)
- Bismark (Germans)
- Montezuma (Aztecs)
- Ashurbanipal (Assyria)
- Wu (China)